# Python not moving past while loop

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

Good day,

I have a script which monitors the input from 2 motion sensors which will turn on a light should motion from either of these 2 sensors be detected (Raspberry Pi 4). After the while loop I have more code that needs to be executed, however, python does not move/continue past the while loop.

Here is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

rightMotionActivity = 3
leftMotionActivity = 5
flashLightControl = 7

GPIO.setup(flashLightControl, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(leftMotionActivity, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(rightMotionActivity, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    leftMotionDetect = GPIO.input(5)
    rightMotionDetect = GPIO.input(3)

    # If both motion sensors are 0
    if leftMotionDetect==0 and rightMotionDetect==0:
        GPIO.output(flashLightControl, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    # If either of the motion sensors are 1
    elif leftMotionDetect==1 or rightMotionDetect==1:
        GPIO.output(flashLightControl, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.1)

# Rest of the code follows but python does not get here
```

Comment: Might have to do with that `while True` up there...

Comment: No break in your while loop, you can move the code want to run to the [if] and [elif]  branch inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the `while True` the while loop will never stop running. You need to implement a manner to get out of the while loop.

Something like this:

```
loopReady = True
while loopReady
    if(sensor1 and sensor2) 
        loopReady = false

#rest of the code
```

if sensor1 and sensor 2 are 'True', loopReady will become false and the while loop exits

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the `while` loop has a condition at the top of the loop, and continues looping until that condition is no longer satisfied.
For, `while True`, we can see that this condition is always `True`. Therefore, the only way to get out of the loop is to use the `break`.
So you could set up a selection statement, which if satisfied will break out of the loop...or you could change the condition at the top.

Answer (score 0):

`while True` means it will continue while true, meaning forever, therefore it will not execute any other code. If you want it to stop some whenever, change the while condition to something else.